# Plus/minus incrementator in Jquery, how to generalize?

Tags: jquery, increment

I'm using this code

```
<a id="minus" href="#">-</a>
   <span id="VALUE">0</span>
<a id="plus" href="#">+</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var valueElement = $('#VALUE');
    function incrementValue(e){
        valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment, 0));
        return false;
    }

    $('#plus').bind('click', {increment: 1}, incrementValue);

    $('#minus').bind('click', {increment: -1}, incrementValue);

});
```

to have a plus/minus incrementator of the filed named "VALUE".
Now, i have a form using this containing 150 field like this... there's a way to generalize this code passing in some way to the function the name of the field that the user is incrementing/decrementing?
Otherwise, i have to replicate this code 150 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one if this helps:

i have changed a little bit i used `classes .plus, .minus` instead of `ids #plus, #minus`

```
 $('.plus').click(function() {
    var sp = parseFloat($(this).prev('span').text());
    $(this).prev('span').text(sp + 1);
 });

 $('.minus').click(function() {
    var sp = parseFloat($(this).next('span').text());
    $(this).next('span').text(sp - 1);
 });
```

check this out in fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/L2UPw/**

Comment: cool! In this way how can i access the values of the span? I tried a $("#value").val() assigning name and id like "value" but it doesn't seem to work. And what about i want to use an input type text instead of a span? Thank you!!

Comment: Solved. I changed to "$(this).next('input').val()" and i could use the "input" instead of the span. Good answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put them inside a container like

```
<span class="stepper">
   <dec>-</dec>
   <span>0</span>
   <inc>+</inc>
</span>
```

This way you can select the display relatively without too much trouble like

```
$(this).parent().children("span");
```

in the respective `click` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of an ID in your selector

```
$('.minus').bind('click', {increment: -1}, incrementValue);
```

and

```
< a id="minus1" class="minus" href="#">-< /a>
...
< a id="minus150" class="minus" href="#">-< /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to genericise your code, then best method would be to use a single class on both elements that affect the value, but add a `data` attribute which is the factor to adjust the amount to add/remove. You can then wrap the controls in a single containing `div` to make DOM traversal easier.

By using this pattern you can have multiple instances of the control on the page, with all buttons governed by a single click handler. Try this:

```js
$('.value-amender').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.closest('.amender-container').find('.value').text(function(i, t) {
    return parseInt(t, 10) + (1 * $el.data('factor'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amender-container">
  <a class="value-amender" href="#" data-factor="-1">-</a>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <a class="value-amender" href="#" data-factor="1">+</a>
</div>

<div class="amender-container">
  <a class="value-amender" href="#" data-factor="-1">-</a>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <a class="value-amender" href="#" data-factor="1">+</a>
</div>
```